# MVC5 Html.EditorForModel not working Properly: NOT showing any string data

Tags: html, model-view-controller, editorformodel

```
Output is showing like: (Only the employee IDs are showing)

1001110012100141001510016;
```

## CODE

## *Editor Template (Location Views\Shared\EditorTemplate\Employee.cshtml*

```
@model MultiRowDEL.Models.Employee
   <tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="empIdsToDel" id="empIdsToDel" value="@Model.EmployeeID" />
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.Name
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.Gender
    </td>
    <td>
        @Model.City 
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not finding the template. The folder should be EditorTemplates (with an s on the end)

Comment: Thanks Steve, But it still did not worked after adding s. However I found an alternate way by using Partial view#                                                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    @Html.Partial("Employee", item)
                    
                }                                                                                                       Instead of using  @Html.EditorForModel()

Comment: Don't use partial. It's bad. It should be @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Employee) or whatever the model's property of type Employee is called in this case.